# Force rescan of the pci device which was wrongly detected by os

Tags: 14.04, networking, kernel, atheros, pci

I am using `ubuntu 14.04.3` , `kernel version 3.13.0-67` with a Atheros Wifi Card `AR93xx` .Many of the times ,no wireless detected on system boot. Below is the problem I detected .

The wireless card should be detected as "Network Controller" by kernel however its detected as "Ethernet Controller" by kernel . Below is the `lspci -nn` command log .

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation ValleyView SSA-CUnit [8086:0f00] (rev 0e)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation ValleyView Gen7 [8086:0f31] (rev 0e)
00:13.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation ValleyView 6-Port SATA AHCI Controller [8086:0f23] (rev 0e)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation ValleyView USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:0f35] (rev 0e)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller [1080]: Intel Corporation ValleyView SEC [8086:0f18] (rev 0e)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation ValleyView High Definition Audio Controller [8086:0f04] (rev 0e)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port [8086:0f48] (rev 0e)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port [8086:0f4a] (rev 0e)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port [8086:0f4c] (rev 0e)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port [8086:0f4e] (rev 0e)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation ValleyView Power Control Unit [8086:0f1c] (rev 0e)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation ValleyView SMBus Controller [8086:0f12] (rev 0e)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:abcd] (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
```

Here's the syslog too which confirms that the device was detected wrong .

```
May 25 19:14:35 ubuntu kernel: [    0.208784] pci 0000:02:00.0: [168c:abcd] type 00 class 0x020000
May 25 19:14:35 ubuntu kernel: [    0.208807] pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xd0700000-0xd071ffff 64bit]
May 25 19:14:35 ubuntu kernel: [    0.208846] pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0xd0720000-0xd072ffff pref]
May 25 19:14:35 ubuntu kernel: [    0.208901] pci 0000:02:00.0: supports D1
May 25 19:14:35 ubuntu kernel: [    0.208905] pci 0000:02:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D3hot
May 25 19:14:35 ubuntu kernel: [    0.208947] pci 0000:02:00.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
```

If the wifi card is detected proper I should see following in `lspci -nn` 
output .

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0030] (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
```

while below lines in syslog .

```
Apr  8 16:44:06 ubuntu kernel: [    0.208677] pci 0000:02:00.0: [168c:0030] type 00 class 0x028000
Apr  8 16:44:06 ubuntu kernel: [    0.208709] pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xd0700000-0xd071ffff 64bit]
Apr  8 16:44:06 ubuntu kernel: [    0.208773] pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0xd0720000-0xd072ffff pref]
```

Solutions I  tried was to remove and rescan the device .

```
sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:02\:00.0/remove"
sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan "
```

but this again shows the same thing . The wireless pci card still detects as Ethernet Controller. I understand that its detected by kernel in a wrong way but than what could be a best way to do a real rescan of the device(without a reboot)  or force the kernel to detect the correct type of device.

Also below is the full log generated by [wireless info script](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info) as recommended on ubuntu forums .

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 30 May 2016 12:32 IST +0530

Booted last: 30 May 2016 11:40 IST +0530

Script from: 26 May 2016 21:56 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.13.0-67-generic #110-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 23 13:24:41 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, text

##### desktop ###########################

sed: can't read /home/ubuntu/.dmrc: No such file or directory

Could not be determined.

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:abcd] (rev 01)

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2055]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

##### lsmod #############################

ath9k                 164164  0 
ath9k_common           13551  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              453856  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    28698  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              630728  1 ath9k
cfg80211              484040  3 ath,ath9k,mac80211

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.20.10
netmask 255.255.255.0

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.53  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'eth0' [IF1]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5616 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4084 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:707839 (707.8 KB)  TX bytes:3170000 (3.1 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 0.0.0.0
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 192.168.1.10
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search domain.name

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

    None found.

##### NetworkManager info ###############

** (process:3060): WARNING **: Could not initialize NMClient /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager: The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files

** (process:3060): WARNING **: error: could not connect to NetworkManager

NetworkManager Tool

State: unknown

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=false
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=<MAC address>,C0:3F:D5:69:4A:55,00:A0:C6:67:04:30,C0:3F:D5:69:72:1C,C0:3F:D5:69:0D:BD,B8:AE:ED:70:45:10,

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Zaya Office 2 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Zaya Office 2 1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Zaya Office 2 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/my Office 3]] (600 root)
[connection] id=my Office 3 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=my Office 3 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/my Office1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=my Office1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=my Office1 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/WRTD-303N_d2f567]] (600 root)
[connection] id=WRTD-303N_d2f567 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=WRTD-303N_d2f567 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Zaya Office 2]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Zaya Office 2 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Zaya Office 2 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/office-3_2GEXT]] (600 root)
[connection] id=office-3_2GEXT | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=office-3_2GEXT | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/office-4]] (600 root)
[connection] id=office-4 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=office-4 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/office-3]] (600 root)
[connection] id=office-3 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=office-3 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/office-3 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=office-3 1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=office-3 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[ath9k]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-67-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     E7A57F092F500DEC330BD56
depends:        ath9k_hw,mac80211,ath9k_common,cfg80211,ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-67-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        2E:7A:AB:A0:3B:9A:BA:73:02:BA:CB:8F:81:3D:80:FF:AC:23:04:50
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           debug:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption (int)
parm:           blink:Enable LED blink on activity (int)
parm:           btcoex_enable:Enable wifi-BT coexistence (int)
parm:           bt_ant_diversity:Enable WLAN/BT RX antenna diversity (int)
parm:           ps_enable:Enable WLAN PowerSave (int)

[ath9k_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-67-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless 802.11n LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     93644B269B570BC55CF5154
depends:        ath,ath9k_hw
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-67-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        2E:7A:AB:A0:3B:9A:BA:73:02:BA:CB:8F:81:3D:80:FF:AC:23:04:50
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[ath9k_hw]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-67-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     65C14EF588BF1A68181643C
depends:        ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-67-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        2E:7A:AB:A0:3B:9A:BA:73:02:BA:CB:8F:81:3D:80:FF:AC:23:04:50
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-67-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     88A67C5359B02C5A710AFCF
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-67-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        2E:7A:AB:A0:3B:9A:BA:73:02:BA:CB:8F:81:3D:80:FF:AC:23:04:50
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-67-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     CD516ABEC909374CB2C52DC
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-67-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        2E:7A:AB:A0:3B:9A:BA:73:02:BA:CB:8F:81:3D:80:FF:AC:23:04:50
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-67-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     695424C2F5CD23A91B67E25
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-67-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        2E:7A:AB:A0:3B:9A:BA:73:02:BA:CB:8F:81:3D:80:FF:AC:23:04:50
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[ath9k]
blink: 0
bt_ant_diversity: 0
btcoex_enable: 0
nohwcrypt: 1
ps_enable: 0

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc
ath9k

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf]
options ath9k nohwcrypt=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

/bin/sh /usr/local/bin/startServer.sh
/bin/echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled 
exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x168c:0x0030 (ath9k)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

########## wireless info END ############
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest upgradeing kernel to 4.4. It has support of new Quallcom wireless adapters. 
Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

and reboot.

Comment: Isn't there a solution to rescan device , upgrading kernel is right now not possible for a very valid reason (our other application stack would broke ). Any workaround would also do for me

Comment: Right now we reboot the device if wireless not detected using a script from rc.local however that can someday might lead to a long reboot loop which I consider a very bad solution . So I needed something which works without reboot

Comment: I did not mean that you will need to reboot every time. Install the new kernel and reboot ONCE. Most likely the problem will go away.

Comment: Yeah I got your point . But can not this problem be solved without upgrading kernel . I mean if somehow I can write a script or a command to rescan for the pci device. I can't upgrade the device's kernel yet for some specific reasons .

Answer (score 0):

So I tried upgrading to recent kernels and found that it was not a problem with kernel but with the wireless card and motherboard integration . The wireless card is connects via pci and talking to manufacturers lead to a conclusion that "the wireless card did not sent proper signals while booting just for a particular board " and thus this problem occurs . However a probable solution seems to restart the device (either manually or by using a script )